# Raspberry Pi RS232 read RFID Transponder

Tags: c, embedded, raspberry-pi

I want to open my door with a RFID Transponder. For this I use a Raspberry Pi and an 125Khz RFID Reader with UART. So now I have written a little C programm, wich sets up the RS232 ('ttyAMA0').  This works all fine, and I can read the Transponder, but it reads some sh**

Here is my Code:

```
char read_rfid(char* rfid_num)
{
    fd_set input_fdset;
    ssize_t length; 
    while(1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&input_fdset);      
        FD_SET(fd,&input_fdset);

        if(select(fd+1 ,&input_fdset, NULL,NULL,NULL)==-1)
            perror("Terminal select() failed");

        if(FD_ISSET(fd,&input_fdset))
        {
            if((length = read(fd,rfid_num,14)) ==-1)
                perror("Terminal: read() failed");
            else
            {
                write(STDOUT_FILENO,rfid_num,length);   
                return;
            }
        }       
    }

}
int setupRS232()
{
    struct termios term_attr;

    if((fd = open(RFID,O_RDWR)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Can't open Device");
        return(1);
    }
    if(tcgetattr(fd,&term_attr) != 0)
    {
        perror("terminal: tcgetattr() failed");
        return(1);
    }
    term_attr.c_cflag = BAUD|CS8|CRTSCTS|CLOCAL|CREAD;
    term_attr.c_iflag = 0;
    term_attr.c_oflag = 0;
    term_attr.c_lflag = 0;
    if(tcsetattr(fd,TCSAFLUSH,&term_attr) != 0)
    {   
       perror("terminal: tcsetattr() failed");
       return(1);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MYSQL *mysql = NULL;    
    char rfid_num[14];
    int i;

    if(init_mysql(mysql) == 1)
        return(1);
    if(setupRS232() == 1)
        return(1);

    puts("Warte auf Transponder...");
    read_rfid(rfid_num);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        printf("%x\n",rfid_num[i]);
    }     
}
```

PS: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: `if((length = read(fd,rfid_num,14)) ==-1)` 1) read can return other values than -1 and 14. Partial reads will be likely, given the ralatively slow serial I/O: you'll have to buffer the received characters until 14 characters have been collected. BTW: a -1 return does not have to be an error (check errno / EAGAIN)

Comment: in your code you do not set any baud rate so most probably you are reading garbage because the baud rates differ. Set the baud rate and try again. Use this as a reference: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal approach to buffering. You should probably check the contents of the buffer before returning valid (is there a final \n ? )

```
char read_rfid(char* rfid_num) {
    fd_set input_fdset;
    ssize_t length;
    int done;

    for(done=0; done < 14; ) {
        FD_ZERO(&input_fdset);
        FD_SET(fd,&input_fdset);

        if(select(fd+1 ,&input_fdset, NULL,NULL,NULL) == -1) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN) continue;
            perror("Terminal select() failed");
            return -1;
            }

        if(FD_ISSET(fd,&input_fdset)) {
            if((length = read(fd,rfid_num+done,14-done)) == -1) {
                if (errno == EAGAIN) continue;
                perror("Terminal: read() failed");
                return -1;
                }
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,rfid_num+done,length);
            done += length;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Note: I don't understand why this function returns `char`.